# How to add and use binary file in android app development

Tags: android, android-developer-api

I want to make a android app which uses a command line tool to carry out tasks but dont know if it is possible and if yes how to do it using kotlin.

For example I want the ls unix command to show a list of files in the directory in the recycler view. So where do I place the ls command binary in the package and how to execute it with kotlin.

Comment: `found some stackoverflow questions but they were not exact. ` Yea, such things happen. What are you going to do against it ? ;-).

Comment: Become the CEO of stackoverflow and gonna get answers of my questions very quick :)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.